# Help with connecting my gear

Tags: midi, daw

I put together a diagram to see how close I am to getting my gear connected. I would like to know if what I have done so far is correct. I also need help with the midi wiring. I get confused with the whole OUT-THRU-IN thing. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Thanks!
Gary

Answer (score 4):

You need to connect the MIDI OUT of your MIDI controller keyboard to the MIDI IN of one of the sound modules, then connect the MIDI THROUGH of that sound module to the MIDI IN of the other. You'll need to put each sound module on a separate MIDI channel.

The MIDI output from your track in the DAW software will need to output on the MIDI channel assigned to the appropriate sound module it's sending MIDI to.

The more sound modules you add the more latency you'll get with this style of "daisy chaining" equipment. If so you may wish to use a MIDI hub.

Sound connections look fine, assuming you have a mixture of line level and mic pre inputs on your audio interface. Which audio interface is it?

Comment: Actually I was hoping that I would be able to use a Yamaha MG166CUSB 16 Input 6 Bus USB Rack Mountable Mixer that I have. Will I still need another piece of hardware?

Comment: It looks like this mixer has 10 Mic and 16 Line level inputs so you should be fine. What are your sound modules? You'll probably just need some 1/4" TS Jack cables to feed the sound module output into the mixer.

Comment: As for the modules, I have the Roland JV-880 as well as the Roland Integra 7. ALSO you said >>> The MIDI output from your track in the DAW software will need to output on the MIDI channel assigned to the appropriate sound module it's sending MIDI to.<<< The only midi cables I will need are to be the controller to module connections right? The mixer will only receive the 1/4" outputs from the modules then USB from mixer to computer?

Comment: Yes the minimum MIDI cables you'll need to send MIDI information from your DAW to the sound modules is two cables. If you want to record some controller movements on either of the sound modules (MIDI CC data), you'll need another cable to go from the MIDI OUT of the sound module you're recording to the MIDI IN of the MIDI controller. It probably won't be necessary if you're just starting out.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I'm beginning to understand. I appreciate everything. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem, I remember starting out, everything was quite overwhelming! You can't do much damage with MIDI, so have fun connecting everything up! I'd advise connecting and testing each piece of gear as you go, rather than plug it all in and expect it to work. Have fun, if you need anything else feel free to contact me, my details are on my profile here.

Comment: Hi Simon (or anyone else who cares to jump in)

Comment: I have come up with a diagram of my actual equipment. I'm sure it's simple, but I want to be sure the connects will be right. Here is a link: http://www.garyblanchettephotography.com/diagram.jpg